# Why aren't my campaign and settings saving?

Tags: battlefield-1

I have just purchased the game on PC. I started it up, did the display-calibration and played the intro (where you die all the time) and played the first campaign mission. After that, I shut the game down, took a break, and wanted to continue later. However, when I started the game I had to do the display-calibration again and also play the whole intro again. My campaign was also not saved.

So basically everytime I shut the game down and restart it, I am at the complete beginning.

Does anybody have the same problem and is there maybe a fix already?

Comment: Out of curiosity, when you started BF1, did Origin say anything about Cloud save data not being syncronized, and if it did, did you choose the online save or the Local save?

Comment: When I start the game a window pops up saying something like "Synchronizing with the cloud..". When it is finished the window closes and the game starts.